# Show bijectivity of function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm having trouble proving that $$f:B_1(0,0) \to \mathbb R^2;\quad f(x) = \frac{x}{1-||x||_2}$$
(where $B_1(0,0)$ denotes the open unit ball with respect to the euclidean norm) is bijective. For injectivity, I started with $$f(a)=f(b) \implies a-a||b|| = b-b||a||$$ 
but can't conclude $a=b$. For surjectivity I don't really know how to start... It seems obvious and I feel really bad not knowing what to do, but maybe one of you can help? Is the Banach Fixed Point Theorem applicable?

Comment: This is just an aside, but note that this is a very cool function. It takes a point in the unit ball of the space, and pushes it outwards in a manner proportional to how near it is to the boundary of the ball. It just expands the ball to cover all of the space.

Comment: I know that it is a homeomorphism from the unit ball in the whole space, and the bijectivity part is what I have to prove :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(x)=y$. $\|y\|(1-\|x\|)=\|x\|)$ this implies $\|x\|={{\|y\|}\over{1+\|y\|}}$ the inverse of $f$ is $g(y)={y\over{1+\|y\|}}$.

Answer (score 1):

For injectivity, note that $a(1-||b||)=b(1-||a||)$ implies $a=b\cdot\frac{1-||a||}{1-||b||}$ and $||a||(1-||b||)=||b||(1-||a||)$, which simplifies to $||a||=||b||$. But then $a=b$.
For surjectivity, I refer to the answer of Tsemo Aristide.

Answer (score 0):

Examine $||f(x)||_2$ -- you find that it is
$$
||f(x)||_2 =\frac{||x||_2}{1-||x||_2}
$$
This implies 
$$ ||x||_2 = \frac{||f(x)||_2 }{||f(x)||_2 +1}$$

Also, note that the ratio of the first and second components of $x$ is the same as that for $f(x)$.  So the point $x$, when described in polar coordinates, uniquely describes $f(x)$.  And $f(x)$ uniqely specifies $x$ since both the radius $||x||_2$ and the direction are determined by $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

For injectivity: By contradiction. Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ with $x\ne y.$ Then one of $x,y ,$ say $x,$ is not the origin. We have $y=Ax$ where $A=(1-\|y\|)/(1-\|x\|).$ We have then $$x/(1-\|x\|)=Ax/(1-\|Ax\|)=Ax/(1-|A|\cdot \|x\|).$$ Since $x\ne (0,0)$ this requires $$1/(1-\|x\|)=A/(1-|A|\cdot \|x\|).$$ Multiplying out the denominators gives $$1-|A|\cdot \|x\|=A-A \|x\|.$$ Now if $A\geq 0$ then $|A|=A$ and we have $1-A\|x\|=A-A\|x\|,$ giving $A=1$, so $y=Ax= x$ which is contrary to $y\ne x.$

On the other hand,if  $A<0$ then $|A|=-A$ and we have $1+A\|x\|=A-A\|x\|,$ giving $0>A=-1/(2\|x\|-1). $ But then $1>\|y\|=\|Ax\|=\|x\|/|(2\|x\|-1)|$ with $2|x\|-1>0,$  giving $2\|x\|-1>\|x\|,$ which is equivalent to $\|x\|>1.$